# What is this 2-D array of numbers called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request

Define $c(n,r)$ ($n\in\Bbb N;r\in\Bbb Z$) by setting $c(0,-1)=-1$, $c(0,0)=1$, and $c(0,r)=0$ otherwise, with all further $c(n, r)$ given recursively by $$c(n+1,r)=rc(n,r-1)-(r+1)c(n,r)$$(rather in the same manner as Pascal's triangle is built). Some patterns in the array are obvious:$$c(n,r)=0\quad\text{ if}\quad n>0\text{ and either }r<0\text{ or }r>n,$$

$$ c(n,0)=(-1)^n,\qquad c(n,1)=(-1)^{n-1}(2^n-1),$$
$\qquad\qquad \qquad\quad \qquad c(n,n)=n!,\qquad c(n,n-1)=-\frac12(n+1)!\quad\text{if }n>0,$ $$\sum_{r=-1}^nc(n,r)=0,$$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. These numbers arise as the coefficients in the formula$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^n(1-x)^k=\sum_{r=-1}^nc(n,r)x^{-r-1}\quad(n\in \Bbb N;\;0<x<2).$$They are probably well known and have a name. Could anyone give me a reference please?

Answer (score 1):

Up to sign, this array seems to appear in numerous contexts, but I don't see a name.  Your array matches the following three OEIS entries, up to sign:  [A028246](http://oeis.org/A028246), [A163626](http://oeis.org/A163626), and [A142071](http://oeis.org/A142071).